# unsuccessfully call external shell script as non-root user

Tags: c, linux, shell, permissions

I want A user to do some jobs as B user. It's OK if B is root, but non-root user failed. Here are basic codes:

root.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    setuid( 0 );
    system( "/tmp/script_of_root.sh" );

    return 0;
}
```

script_of_root.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $RANDOM >> /tmp/file_of_root
```

**playback**:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cc root.c -o root
$ su -
# chown root.root /tmp/root
# chmod 4755 /tmp/root
# exit
$ ./root
```

After executing "./root", file "/tmp/file_of_root" will be updated. But if I apply the same thing to a non-root user, it doesn't work. Codes:

foobar.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    setuid( 1001 );    // uid of user "foobar"
    system( "/tmp/script_of_foobar.sh" );

    return 0;
}
```

script_of_foobar.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $RANDOM >> /tmp/file_of_foobar
```

**playback**:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cc foobar.c -o foobar
$ su -
# chown foobar.users /tmp/foobar
# chmod 4755 /tmp/foobar
# exit
$ ./foobar
```

If I run "./foobar" as other normal user(not "foobar" itself), it's gonna be error:

```
/tmp/script_of_foobar.sh: line 2: file_of_foobar: Permission denied
```

I am totally confused. Why the second scenario not working?

Best regards.

Comment: Can you check the return value from your `setuid(1001)` call and `perror()` if the result isn't zero?

Comment: What are the permissions of `/tmp`?  Does the `foobar` user have write permission to `/tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

The setuid call in foobar.c will only succeed if you are root, or your effective UID is 1001.

So. If you're not root, setuid(1001) will fail, and you won't have the required rights to overwrite the file owned by "foobar".

Comment: Try seteuid(1001). You've got the setuid bit set on the binary, but just to make sure you haven't mucked things up, I'd suggest that you printf ("%d\n", geteuid ()); just before you invoke system().

Answer (score 0):

From the output it looks like your non-root user is able to execute script_of_foobar.sh, but unable to write to /tmp/file_of_foobar.  Are the permissions on /tmp possibly off?  I believe it should be set to 1777.